# Ionic app automated testing using Appium and protractor file upload not working

Tags: protractor, appium

I am testing ionic app. 
Using appium and protractor

**Input field**

```
<input type="file" id="fileLabtest" style="display:none">
```

**Test script code**

```
var fileElem = element(by.css('[id="fileLabtest"]'));
fileElem.sendKeys('/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/IMG_20180301_133955.jpg');
```

It will through error file not found.

Comment: Then you need to give correct path for the file.

Comment: above path is correct path i have find this path from android shell